# T-SQL error with IIF keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following sql comparison using `IIF` keyword

```
DECLARE @a int, @b int
SET @a = 10
SET @b = 20

BEGIN
   SELECT IIF( @a < @b, 'True', 'False') As Result
END
```

However, on execution it gives an error

```
Incorrect syntax near '<'
```

What is causing this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  `IIF` is only available SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: What version are you on? It was only introduced for [2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).

Comment: @bluefeet - technically, it's available in the CTP of 2014 too :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, updated to 2012+. :)

Comment: @bluefeet: That probably explains why. I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `IIF` is a new function in SQL Server 2012+, so you'll have to use a `CASE` statement instead:

```
DECLARE @a int, @b int
SET @a = 10
SET @b = 20

BEGIN
   SELECT CASE WHEN @a < @b THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END As Result
END
```

Answer (score 2):

IIF was used in VBA, but not available in SQL Server until the 2012 release.  use the SELECT CASE statement instead.

```
DECLARE @a int, @b int
SET @a = 10
SET @b = 20

BEGIN
   SELECT CASE WHEN @a < @b THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END As Result
END
```